# issue with vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm a beginner, I was trying to use the command "vagrant up" to set up a virtual machine, but I keep getting this:

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to initialize correctly. This may be due to manual
modifications made within the Vagrant home directory. Vagrant can
attempt to automatically correct this issue by running:

  vagrant plugin repair

If Vagrant was recently updated, this error may be due to incompatible
versions of dependencies. To fix this problem please remove and re-install
all plugins. Vagrant can attempt to do this automatically by running:

  vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall

Or you may want to try updating the installed plugins to their latest
versions:

  vagrant plugin update

Error message given during initialization: incompatible character encodings: CP850 and Windows-1252
```

This is getting SO frustrating, I tried to find solutions for hours, tried using `vagrant plugin repair`, `vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall`, `vagrant plugin update`, reinstalling Vagrant SEVERAL times... Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage

Is often caused by problems on your system, not by vagrant.

Your final error message is:
`Error message given during initialization: incompatible character encodings: CP850 and Windows-1252`

This problem is described [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/3937).

The solution given is: to type `chcp 1252` on the commandline before you type `vagrant up`.

I could find this answer by searching on `CP850 vs Windows-1252 vagrant`

When you encounter a problem like this you should always just put the error message or keywords based on it in a search engine. Big chance someone else encounterded and solved the problem.